# replace placeholder tags with dictionary fields in python

Tags: python, regex

this is my code so far:

```
import re
template="Hello,my name is [name],today is [date] and the weather is [weather]"
placeholder=re.compile('(\[([a-z]+)\])')
find_tags=placeholder.findall(cam.template_id.text)
fields={field_name:'Michael',field_date:'21/06/2015',field_weather:'sunny'}

for key,placeholder in find_tags:
assemble_msg=template.replace(placeholder,?????)
print assemble_msg
```

I want to replace every tag with the associated dictionary field and the final message to be like this:
My name is Michael,today is 21/06/2015 and the weather is sunny.
I want to do this automatically and not manually.I am sure that the solution is simple,but I couldn't find any so far.Any help?

Comment: Try running this piece of code and see if it's applicable to your problem: `'My name is {name}'.format(name='Ian')`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for a manual solution using regular expressions. This is (in a slightly different format) already supported by [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> template = "Hello, my name is {name}, today is {date} and the weather is {weather}"
>>> fields = {'name': 'Michael', 'date': '21/06/2015', 'weather': 'sunny'}
>>> template.format(**fields)
Hello, my name is Michael, today is 21/06/2015 and the weather is sunny
```

If you can not alter your `template` string accordingly, you can easily replace the `[]` with `{}` in a preprocessing step. But note that this will raise a `KeyError` in case one of the placeholders is not present in the `fields` dict.

---

In case you want to keep your manual approach, you could try like this:

```
template = "Hello, my name is [name], today is [date] and the weather is [weather]"
fields = {'field_name': 'Michael', 'field_date': '21/06/2015', 'field_weather': 'sunny'}
for placeholder, key in re.findall('(\[([a-z]+)\])', template):
    template = template.replace(placeholder, fields.get('field_' + key, placeholder))
```

Or a bit simpler, without using regular expressions:

```
for key in fields:
    placeholder = "[%s]" % key[6:]
    template = template.replace(placeholder, fields[key])
```

Afterwards, `template` is the new string with replacements. If you need to keep the template, just create a copy of that string and do the replacement in that copy. In this version, if a placeholder can not be resolved, it stays in the string. (Note that I swapped the meaning of `key` and `placeholder` in the loop, because IMHO it makes more sense that way.)

Comment: This is the proper way to formatting of this nature. If the OP needs to keep template: `new_var = template.format(**fields)` and the value of template will remain the same.

Comment: Actually @tobias_k the final message is not right.if you print the message in every loop, you will see that replaces every time the associated tag, but when it fixes the second tag for example ,the first one is [name].and when it goes to change tag to the third one ,the others are [name] and [date].

Comment: @pankar You must be doing `new_string = template.replace(...)`. This way, it uses the original template each time. Do `template = template.replace(...)` or `new_string = template` and then `new_string = new_string.replace(...)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionaries to put data straight into strings, like so...

```
fields={'field_name':'Michael','field_date':'21/06/2015','field_weather':'sunny'}
string="Hello,my name is %(field_name)s,today is %(field_date)s and the weather is %(field_weather)s" % fields
```

This might be an easier alternative for you?